# Read a column of dates from Excel into zoo (or xts)

Tags: r, date, csv, zoo, import-from-excel

I have a column of dates, exported from Excel as CSV into dataframe, the default type in "import dataset..." "...from CSV" i.e. `d<-read_csv(data.csv)`. 
From a dataframe I like to create a zoo and/or xts object.

The data is:

```
30/04/2016
31/05/2016
30/06/2016
```

I get the following errors:

```
dates <- c('30/04/2016','31/05/2016','30/06/2016')
d <- dates
z <- read.zoo(d)
```

> Error in read.zoo(d) : index has bad entry at data row 1

```
z <- read.zoo(d, FUN = as.Date())
```

> Error in as.Date() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

```
z <- read.zoo(d, FUN = as.Date(format="%d/%m/%Y"))
```

> Error in as.Date(format = "%d/%m/%Y") :    argument "x" is missing,
>   with no default

Alternatively, if i read directly into zoo with format arguemnt i get a different error:

```
ts.z <- read.zoo(d,index=1,tz='',format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

> Error in read.zoo(d, index = 1, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y") :
>   index has bad entry at data row 1

What are the bad entry row 1 errors? What are the correct ways to specify FUN = ? What are the correct input classes and distinctions for read.zoo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?read.zoo` about the `file`-parameter:

> character string or strings giving the name of the file(s) which the
>   data are to be read from/written to. See `read.table` and
>   `write.table` for more information. Alternatively, in `read.zoo`, file
>   can be a connection or a data.frame (e.g., resulting from a previous
>   `read.table` call) that is subsequently processed to a "zoo" series.

What is going wrong in your example is that `d` is neither a filename, a connection or a data.frame. You will have to wrap it in `data.frame()`.

A working example:

```
z <- read.zoo(data.frame(dates), FUN = as.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

which gives:

```
> z

2016-04-30
2016-05-31
2016-06-30
> class(z)
[1] "zoo"
```

---

Used input data:

```
dates <- c('30/04/2016','31/05/2016','30/06/2016')
```